# C++ Templates - Specifying a container type and that containers element type that it holds

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

I want to be able to create a function where I specify a parameter to have both a templated container and a templated element type for that container.  Is this possible?  I get "error C2988: unrecongnizable template declaration/definition" among others.  Here is the function in question.

```
template<class Iter, class Elem>
 void readIntoP(Iter<Elem> aCont){
ifstream ifss("data.dat");
string aString;
int counter = 0;
item tempItem;
while(ifss >> aString){
    istringstream iss(aString);
    if(counter == 0){
        tempItem.name = aString;
    }else if(counter == 1){
        int aNum = 0;
        iss >> aNum;
        tempItem.iid = aNum;
    }else{
        double aNum = 0;
        iss >> aNum;
        tempItem.value = aNum;
        aCont.push_back(tempItem);
        counter = -1;
    }
    ++counter;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Sort-of duplicate of [c++ function template compiles error "‘containerType’ is not a template"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436518/c-function-template-compiles-error-containertype-is-not-a-template) (the solution is exactly the same, at least).

Comment: Related: [check type of element in stl container - c++ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708867/check-type-of-element-in-stl-container-c)

Answer (score 6):

You would need to use a template template parameter, e.g.,

```
template <template <class> class Iter, class Elem>
void readIntoP(Iter<Elem> aCont) { /* ... */ }
```

Note, however, that the standard library containers take multiple template parameters (`vector`, for example, takes two:  one for the value type to be stored and one for the allocator to use).

You might instead use a single template parameter for the instantiated container type and then use its `value_type` typedef:

```
template <typename ContainerT>
void readIntoP(ContainerT aCont)
{
    typedef typename ContainerT::value_type ElementT;
    // use ContainerT and ElementT
}
```

Comment: It's usually better to parameterize on iterators than on containers. (Which is what OP is doing.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  It's hard to tell.  The question title and variable name imply the OP is attempting to pass a container; the typename implies the OP is attempting to pass an iterator of some sort.  Either way, iterators also have a `value_type` typedef.  I'd agree that in general it is better to pass iterators around instead of containers, but often it is useful to pass a whole container.

Comment: I've heard that the standard doesn't specify how many parameters a container has. A vector has at least two, but implementation may add more for their own purposes, making "template templates" less portable?

Comment: @UncleBens: Johannes Schaub asked [a question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469743/standard-library-containers-with-additional-optional-template-parameters) and the answer was that the standard does specify exactly what the parameters of a container must be

Comment: @James McNellis -> Could you describe the understanding of how the template parameter 'template <class> class Iter' works (I'm having trouble following the logic).

Also, I'm interested, why is parameterizing on iterators better than on containers?

btw, thanks for all your extremely quick answers! :d


P.S. 
@James McNellis & Potatoswatter  ->  Sorry about the misunderstanding with my template being called 'iter'.  I was at first going to go the iterator route, but then decided to try this container route, but forgot to change it appropriatly.

Comment: @Gijera:  A template template parameter allows you to instantiate a template with a template as its argument instead of with a type as its argument.  So, in my example, you could instantiate `readIntoP` with any template that itself has a single template parameter.  For more information, I'd recommend picking up a copy of _C++ Templates:  The Complete Guide_, which is the definitive book on the workings of C++ templates.  As for why iterators are better than containers:  they add an extra layer of abstraction and let you deal with ranges of values more generically.