# How to handle nested type template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

Can anyone help me with this errors. When i compile this simple program

```
#include<queue> 
using namespace std;
template<typename Queue>
int qtest(Queue & queue,typename Queue::Type item)
 {
    return 0;
 }

int main()
{
    std::queue<int> q;
    int t = qtest(q,3);
}
```

I get the errors like below

```
In function 'int main()':
error: no matching function for call to 'qtest(std::queue<int>&, int)'
note: candidate is:
note: template<class Queue> int qtest(Queue&, typename Queue::Type)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
 In substitution of 'template<class Queue> int qtest(Queue&, typename Queue::Type) [with 
Queue = std::queue<int>]':
   required from here
error: no type named 'Type' in 'class std::queue<int>'
warning: unused variable 't' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Comment: error: no type named 'Type' in 'class std::queue<int>'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Templates - Specifying a container type and that containers element type that it holds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454373/c-templates-specifying-a-container-type-and-that-containers-element-type-tha)

Answer (score 3):

`std::queue` doesn't have a member type called `Type`. That's what the compiler is telling us. I'm guessing what you're looking for is `std::queue<int>::value_type`.

```cpp
template<typename Queue>
int qtest(Queue & queue,typename Queue::value_type item)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Reference: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)